# What marketplace was my app downloaded from

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is there any code that I can run in my app to figure out what marketplace my app was downloaded from?

Comment: What other marketplaces exist beside the standard Windows Phone marketplace?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if the app was downloaded from the UK marketplace or the US marketplace or where...

Answer (score 0):

Check system culture settings, it will be the same as Marketplace where your app has been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can check system culture info. But sometimes, users can switch to other marketplace to download app.

Answer (score 0):

what crea7or said is almost correct, Normally through the app you cannot predict the region it was downloaded from, but if it is for the first time then checking the culture settings immediately after downloading the app could let you know this. Otherwise the xap is not packaged with the information about the region it was download from.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` on first install of the app.